# Unable to draw a triangle in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, rendering, directx, directx-11

I am learning DirectX 11 and trying to render a triangle, but nothing show up except the background color. There is no errors, no warnings. Here is my main file:

```
while (true)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            break;
        }
        // Rendering here
        ID3D11Buffer* vertex_buffer;

        const float color[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        device_context->ClearRenderTargetView(render_target_view, color);

        Vertex vertices[]{
            { 0.0f, -0.5f},
            { 0.5f,  0.5f},
            {-0.5f, -0.5f}
        };

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vb_desc;
        ZeroMemory(&vb_desc, sizeof(vb_desc));
        vb_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices);
        vb_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        vb_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        vb_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        vb_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
        vb_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Vertex);

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vb_data;
        ZeroMemory(&vb_data, sizeof(vb_data));
        vb_data.pSysMem = vertices;

        device->CreateBuffer(&vb_desc, &vb_data, &vertex_buffer);

        const UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
        const UINT offset = 0;

        device_context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertex_buffer, &stride, &offset);

        ID3D11VertexShader *vertex_shader;
        ID3D11PixelShader* pixel_shader;
        ID3DBlob* result_blob;
        ID3DBlob* error_blob;
        D3DCompileFromFile(L"PixelShader.hlsl", NULL, NULL, "main", "ps_4_0", D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG, 0, &result_blob, &error_blob);
        device->CreatePixelShader(result_blob->GetBufferPointer(), result_blob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &pixel_shader);
        device_context->PSSetShader(pixel_shader, nullptr, 0);

        D3DCompileFromFile(L"VertexShader.hlsl", NULL, NULL, "main", "vs_4_0", D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG, 0, &result_blob, &error_blob);
        
        device->CreateVertexShader(result_blob->GetBufferPointer(), result_blob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &vertex_shader);

        device_context->VSSetShader(vertex_shader, nullptr, 0);

        ID3D11InputLayout *input_layout;

        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC element_desc[] =
        {
            {"Position", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
        };

        device->CreateInputLayout(element_desc, 1, result_blob->GetBufferPointer(), result_blob->GetBufferSize(), &input_layout);

        device_context->IASetInputLayout(input_layout);

        result_blob->Release();
        if (error_blob != nullptr) error_blob->Release();


        device_context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

        device_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, &render_target_view, nullptr);

        D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
        vp.Width = 800;
        vp.Height = 600;
        vp.MinDepth = 0;
        vp.MaxDepth = 1;
        vp.TopLeftX = 0;
        vp.TopLeftY = 0;
        device_context->RSSetViewports(1u, &vp);


        device_context->Draw(3, 0);

        vertex_buffer->Release();
        vertex_shader->Release();
        pixel_shader->Release();
        input_layout->Release();

        swap_chain->Present(1u, 0u);

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    device->Release();
    device_context->Release();
    swap_chain->Release();
    render_target_view->Release();
```

This is the vertex shader(named VertexShader.hlsl):

```
float4 main(float2 pos : Position) : SV_Position
{
    return float4(pos.x, pos.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

And here is the pixel shader(named PixelShader.hlsl):

```
float4 main() : SV_Target
{
    return float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

I appreciate any hint to solve this.
Thank you for helping.

**EDIT**
Thanks @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes for helping me with this problem. The solution is changing the coordinate of the vertices to

```
    Vertex vertices[]{
            { 0.0f, 0.5f},
            { 0.5f,-0.5f},
            {-0.5f, -0.5f}
        };
```

Comment: You never check for `HRESULT`. Maybe a function call somewhere fails.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Ok, so I tried it. I create a `HRESULT` and check FAILED for functions that return `HRESULT` and MessageBox it but nothing show up, just a black window

Comment: Looks like it's time for shotgun debugging then. Two more ideas:
- Is the window painted black, or your background color? (ie. try setting a different bg color, and see whether it stays black, or gets painted that color)
- I don't know much about D3D11 (only learned D3D12), but you never set an explicit pipeline state. Are you sure that is not necessary / that the default states do what you want?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes The window is painted black   using`ClearRenderTargetView()` and I can easily change the color. I think the pipeline state is a new thing in DirectX 12 (Pipeline state object maybe) which DirectX 11 do not have. I don't know much about DirectX 12

Comment: The pipeline state object itself (`ID3D12GraphicsPipelineState`, if I recall correctly) is not in DX11, as here you have to handle each stage of the pipeline separately. For example, there's a [`ID3D11RasterizerState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11rasterizerstate) solely for the rasterizer (could be what you need, considering the triangle seems to simply be not on your screen. I'm guessing at this point though.)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Hehe, just playing around with my code and found out that my vertex buffer was mixed and incorrect. It supposed to be Vertex vertices[]{
   { 0.0f, 0.5f},
   { 0.5f,-0.5f},
   {-0.5f, -0.5f}
  }; Sorry for wasting your time. Really appreciate your help, you are learning DirectX 12 but still helping me in learning DirectX 11.Once again, thanks alot !

Comment: Ah yes, you had them counterclockwise, huh? By the way, if you ever use a custom rasterizer state, you can change it there (you can explicitly set counterclockwise triangles as front facing (ie. to-be-drawn))

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Oooh, nice. Have to use it now to avoid that annoying bug!

Comment: Just a technical note, that last paragraph you edited in would look better as an answer. Answering your own questions is perfectly normal and encouraged on SO, as it also helps whomever happens to be googling the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes noted, the primary reason you see nothing is the 'winding order' of the triangles due to [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling). This is because you are using the 'default' DirectX 11 "Rasterizer State object" which is as follows from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc):

| State | Default Value |
| --- | --- |
| FillMode | Solid |
| CullMode | Back |
| FrontCounterClockwise | FALSE |
| DepthBias | 0 |
| SlopeScaledDepthBias | 0.0f |
| DepthBiasClamp | 0.0f |
| DepthClipEnable | TRUE |
| ScissorEnable | FALSE |
| MultisampleEnable | FALSE |
| AntialiasedLineEnable | FALSE |

You can make your triangle visible by:

1. Changing the vertices so they have a different winding-order
2. You can create and set a new RasterizerState object with a cull mode of `D3D11_CULL_FRONT` or `D3D11_CULL_NONE` instead of `D3D11_CULL_BACK`.
3. You can create and set a new RasterizerState object with a FrontCounterClockwise of TRUE instead of FALSE.

> Your loop currently creates and destroys the buffers, shaders objects, input layout every frame. You should reuse them each frame instead.

> You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) as well as [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).